# <Not about to V> vs <About to V>

Tags: phrases

***Not about to***
Not going to (do something), typically because of unwillingness.
Be unwilling to do something

1. I'm not about to work this sunday.
2. Jane wasn't about to pay all that extra money.

***About to***
on the point of doing something

1. She was about to head out the door
2. You are about to see something amazing.

So, ***about to*** and ***not about to*** has totally different meaning right?
I mean one is not the negative of the other

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**not about to** can be the simple negative of **about to**, but it can have the added implication of unwillingness.

> Are you about to leave?
>   --No, I'm not about to leave. I intend to stay a while longer.
>
> We're not about to divulge our secret recipe!

Equally, **about to** can mean "at the point of doing something" or it can imply **willingness**.

> I'm about to give you a good swift kick, kiddo. You can play video games after you do your homework.